# Enable Preemptible on existing GCP Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

How do I enable preemptible on an existing GCP Compute Engine VM? I don't want to have to delete and recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to change the preemptible status of a running VM instance.

A VM is determined to be preemptible or normal at creation time, and can't be upgraded or downgraded once created.

However, you can [create a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of your existing VM instance and using that snapshot you can [Creating a Preemptible VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-preemptible-instance). For more information about how to [Creating an instance from a snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot) follow this article.